# How to play Audio with If condition by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to play audio automatically when the If condition is true and I tried to write this code in my index.html file but didn't play the sound file!

I tried it with button click and worked but I need it with IF condition automatically when IF condition is true

```
<script>
  var sound1 = new Audio('services.mp3'); 

   var name = function() {
    if( 29 == 29 ){
      sound1.play();
    }
    else {
      sound1.play();
    }

   }
</script>
```

I tried that code and when I reload the page nothing heard! and in console debugger no errors!

Any Idea please!

Thanks

Comment: Your `if` condition is within a function. I do not see any code which invoke this function? Also, you  are invoking `play` in both `if` and `else` which does not make any sense. What is 29? and what does this condition `29 == 29` mean? Code readability matter a lot.

Comment: @randomSoul it is just like a test to check playing audio

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear to me that you're actually invoking your function. Maybe try this?

```
<script>
var sound1 = new Audio('services.mp3');
var playSound = function() {
    if( 29 == 29 ){
       sound1.play();
    }
    else {
        sound1.play();
    }
};

playSound(); // Invoke playSound function

</script>
```

I changed the name of your function from `name` to `playSound` as it conflicts with `window.name` (mentioned by @randomSoul)

Comment: `name` declared above is in global scope and is conflicting with `window.name`.  Make it local using let or IIFE.

Comment: @mwilson  it gave me `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` and `Anonymous` !

Comment: I'd check out @randomSoul 's answer. It looks like `.play` returns a promise (which would explain why your running into that error)

Answer (score 0):

`video` or `audio` play is an asynchronous activity and it returns `promise` - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted.

```js
let playPromise = new Audio('car_horn.wav');
playPromise.play().then(() => {
    console.log('Playing')
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log('Error Occured', e.message);
})
```

Comment: it works with Microsoft Edge but not in chrome neither in Firefox!